# Which query will be better in terms of perfomance SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

I have written two queries and I need help to know which one will be better in term of performance. Both do the same thing. Please also advise if you have better a way of writing the query

Query 1

```
DECLARE @TotalAvailedLateNightGeneral INT

;WITH CTE (TotalDaysAppliedFor) AS (
    SELECT SUM(TotalDaysAppliedFor) AS TotalDaysAppliedFor
    FROM [CURFEW_RLX_REQUEST] WITH (NOLOCK)
    GROUP BY StaffSeqId, RequestTypeId, MONTH(PermissionRequiredFrom), StatusId, IsActive
    HAVING StaffSeqId = 41130
        AND RequestTypeId = 3
        AND MONTH(PermissionRequiredFrom) = MONTH('2016-03-30 00:00:00.000')
        AND StatusId <> 111
        AND IsActive = 1
)
SELECT @TotalAvailedLateNightGeneral = SUM(TotalDaysAppliedFor)
FROM CTE

SELECT @TotalAvailedLateNightGeneral
```

QUERY 2

```
SELECT SUM(TotalDaysAppliedFor) AS TotalDaysAppliedFor
FROM [CURFEW_RLX_REQUEST] WITH (NOLOCK)
--GROUP BY StaffSeqId,RequestTypeId,MONTH(PermissionRequiredFrom),StatusId,IsActive
WHERE StaffSeqId = 41130
    AND RequestTypeId = 3
    AND MONTH(PermissionRequiredFrom) = MONTH('2016-03-30 00:00:00.000')
    AND StatusId <> 111
    AND IsActive = 1
```

Comment: Have you tested it? If you have two horses and you want to know which is faster, race the horses.

Comment: Please provide execution plan for second query...

Comment: your queries are not Sargable,see Devart example

Comment: Both have nolock, both'll hurtle like a rocket.

Comment: Since in Query 1 there is extra layer of cte and doing unnecessary grouping will it matter in performance even 1/1000 of second .. I am taking about theoretical performance

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2016-03-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2016-04-01'

SELECT TotalDaysAppliedFor = SUM(TotalDaysAppliedFor)
FROM dbo.QAG_GEMS_CURFEW_RLX_REQUEST
WHERE StaffSeqId = 41130
    AND RequestTypeId = 3
    AND PermissionRequiredFrom >= @StartDate
    AND PermissionRequiredFrom < @EndDate
    AND StatusId != 111
    AND IsActive = 1
```